# WPF RadioButton styled as ToggleButton not displaying initial value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, caliburn.micro

I have three radio buttons bound (with Caliburn.Micro) to three properties of a viewmodel. All the properties seem correct and I debug to see that the selected property is returning True and that the control has IsChecked = true and the property notifiers seem to to be raising ok, but when I first open the form none of the toggle buttons appear selected. If I start clicking them everything works fine, its only on the initial load that the selected value isn't "pressed". This is the XAML...

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Alignment" Name="FooterLeftAlign" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v15.1;component/Images/Format/AlignLeft_16x16.png" Margin="0" />
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="Alignment" Name="FooterCenterAlign" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v15.1;component/Images/Format/AlignCenter_16x16.png"  Margin="0" />
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="Alignment" Name="FooterRightAlign" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v15.1;component/Images/Format/AlignRight_16x16.png" Margin="0" />
</RadioButton>
```

And here are the properties...

```
public bool FooterLeftAlign {
        get {
            return (ScannerSettings.StampOptions.TextAlign == TextAlignment.Left);
        }
        set {
            if (value) {
                ScannerSettings.StampOptions.TextAlign = TextAlignment.Left;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FooterLeftAlign);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool FooterCenterAlign {
        get {
            return (ScannerSettings.StampOptions.TextAlign == TextAlignment.Center);
        }
        set {
            if (value) {
                ScannerSettings.StampOptions.TextAlign = TextAlignment.Center;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FooterCenterAlign);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool FooterRightAlign {
        get {
            return (ScannerSettings.StampOptions.TextAlign == TextAlignment.Right);
        }
        set {
            if (value) {
                ScannerSettings.StampOptions.TextAlign = TextAlignment.Right;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FooterRightAlign);
            }
        }
    }
```

I even have some actual ToggleButtons on this form for Bold, Italics, etc... and they work fine. I've seen plenty of examples of forcing custom styles with triggers on it, but I want to make sure it looks like the other toggle buttons. Since I've seen other examples very similar to this the only thing I could think of is the fact we have a DevExpress theme, but couldn't find anything that looked like it would change this behavior.

If anyone has any suggestions it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those radio buttons don't seem to have IsChecked bound to anything...  are you setting their values someplace else?

Comment: Sorry thanks for pointing that out, they are being bound using Caliburn.Micro.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `((RadioButton)FooterRightAlign).IsChecked = value` if this is code-behind. If this is actually an MVVM situation, you need to bind each of your radiobuttons to these bools.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Alignment" Name="FooterRightAlign" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" IsChecked="{Binding FooterRightAlign, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v15.1;component/Images/Format/AlignRight_16x16.png" Margin="0" />
```

Comment: The binding is from CalibrunMicro and appears to work fine when clicking buttons I did try manual setting IsClicked during load and it still did not seem to update the UI accordingly. I see during load of the dialog that its querying my properties and getting back the correct values and IsClicked even seems to be true on the control. It's like something in the style isn't getting triggered correctly.

Comment: ((RadioButton)FooterRightAlign).IsChecked = value; won't work because you have radiobuttons named the same thing as bool properties.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CalibrunMicro, so this seems very foreign to me.

Comment: It's simply a framework that autobinds things e.g. FooterRightAlign ui element is automaticaly bound to {DataContext}.FooterRightAlign property.

Comment: I'd try setting IsChecked on the Window.Loaded event in code behind. `public MainWindow(){this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;}` then in `MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){ ((RadioButton)FooterRightAlign.IsChecked = ((ViewModelType)this.DataContext).FooterRightAlign;}`

Comment: I tried it and a few other places like the data context changed event etc... and it didn't have any effect and actuall IsClicked was already set to true correctly. It seems to be some UI issue.